# Stack trace on multiple lines in log file

Tags: php, logging, typo3, typo3-11.x

How can I configure Typo3 / PHP to print stack traces line by line in the log file instead of one line with entries separated by visible `\n`?

This could be a problem of PHP in general. I remember having seen full stack traces on single lines in multiple PHP applications.

In Java you always get a readable stack trace where each function call is printed on a separate line. For example:

```
Exception ... 
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:242)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1632)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
...
```

This is how a recent error looks in Typo3/PHP:

```
Fri, 11 Nov 2022 12:06:44 +0000 [ERROR] request="bd7a1ccef67a2" component="ApacheSolrForTypo3.Solr.IndexQueue.FrontendHelper.PageIndexer": Exception while trying to index page 7 - ["Exception: Could not connect to Solr server. in /opt/myapp/public/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/Typo3PageIndexer.php:223\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/myapp/public/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/IndexQueue/FrontendHelper/PageIndexer.php(276): ApacheSolrForTypo3\\Solr\\Typo3PageIndexer->setSolrConnection()\n#1 [internal function]: ApacheSolrForTypo3\\Solr\\IndexQueue\\FrontendHelper\\PageIndexer->hook_indexContent()\n#2 /opt/myapp/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php(3129): call_user_func_array()\n#3 /opt/myapp/public/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(2622): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Utility\\GeneralUtility::callUserFunction()\n#4 /opt/myapp/public/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Http/RequestHandler.php(146): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController->generatePage_postProcessing()\n#5 /opt/myapp/public/typo3conf/ext/vhs/Classes/Middleware/AssetInclusion.php(20): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\RequestHandler->handle()\n#6 /opt/myapp/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): FluidTYPO3\\Vhs\\Middleware\\AssetInclusion->process()\n#7 /opt/myapp/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Middleware/ResponsePropagation.php(34): Psr\\Http\\Server\\RequestHandlerInterface@anonymous->handle()\n#8 /opt/myapp/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Middleware\\ResponsePropagation->process()\n(...)
```

Comment: This is almost certainly an artifact of system logging.  PHP is correctly emitting a formatted string to stderr (the only correct use of stderr is for actual errors) and then the receiving endpoint is dumping that error message into the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to change the log format in TYPO3 but for me, the TYPO3 Extension [Logformatter](https://github.com/sudhaus7/typo3-logformatter) is very helpful to get readable log output.